# Application of Derivative - nth order subtangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem : Show that subtangent to the parabola of the nth order
$y=x^n$ is n times less than the abscissa of the point of tangency.

Sol :

If $y =x^n$, then $y' = nx^{n-1}$ Let us consider point (a,b) then slope at this point will be :

$m = na^{n-1}$

Please guide how to proceed for this complete proof... Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: my definitions of subtangent and abscissa are from wikipedia

By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) ([subtangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtangent)) the abscissa of $(a,b)$ is $a$ and the subtangent of $y$  is $\frac{y}{\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}}$ so

$$
\text{abcissa} = a \\
\text{subtangent} = \frac{x^n}{n x^{n-1}} = \frac{x}{n} = \frac{a}{n}
$$

so then it's clear that the subtangent is $n$ times less than the abscissa